# Info on '#!' (shebang, hashbang, crunchbang, etc.)

Tags: bash, python, shebang

I have a question about the phrase '#!' that appears at the top of every python file, most bash files, and several others.

I've already performed a search for this term on both Google and this website.  Google just refers me to the bash documentation, and Super User gives me exactly 0 search results.

So, here are my questions:

- Is there any use for the phrase '#!' in any part of an interpreted executable file aside from the top line, which shows the primary interpreter to use?
- If so, can it be used to switch interpreters while in the same shell, or is it used for something else?
- Are there any other types of commands that can be sent to the interpreting shell like this one?

Comment: Take a look at http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam.html

Comment: We are not a discussion forum, so lets not "talk" about anything, this question seems overly broad.

Comment: Cyrus, thanks for the link!  Ramhound, it's not a discussion, it's an honest-to-god question, just with an oddly phrased intoduction.  Also, it's not that broad, just 3 yeses and nos.

Comment: @user5249751 - So pick a different title.  Does not even describe the proposed question, which should be a single question, not multiple ones

Comment: Unfortunately, here are too many unqualified reviewers: [1](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/420168) [2](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/420181). Could someone please add tag [tag:shebang] (`#!`)? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ is probably the best resource.

Comment: @Cyrus: tags shouldn't introduce/presuppose answers or introduce terms not used in the question.  Also, when a question needs significant editing, adding a tag and not touching anything else isn't adequate.

Comment: You [searched Super User for "shebang"](http://superuser.com/search?q=shebang) and didn't find *anything*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hashbang" as it is known is only useful when it appears at the beginning of a file. When a file is executed from a *nix shell that starts with those two bytes, the following pathname is called to interpret the remainder of the file. This allows interpreted scripts to be treated on the same level as compiled binary executables.

The shell passes the entire file to the interpreter, and so the other reason for starting with # is that it will let the first line be treated as a comment by the interpreter.

The answers to your other questions are both no -- you can't switch interpreters halfway through a file (unless you send a different instruction to the first interpreter that does this), and there are no other embedded "commands" that can be interpreted by the shell when attempting to execute a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It is called shebang. Interpreters ignore it as the line begins with '#' and it means it's a comment, but for the system it tells what to do with that code on execution. The path after the '#!' is the path of the interpreter, and if you run the code, it will open the file with the interpreter you gave in the shebang.